# error in compilation while looping over map

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

got compilation error while trying to compile simple cpp program

i have tried the following compilation lines

```
1) gcc hello.cpp -std=gnu++11
2) g++ hello.cpp -std=gnu++11
```

this is my cpp file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
static map<string,int> create_map()
{
  map<string,int> mymap = {
                { "alpha", 10 },
                { "beta", 20 },
                { "gamma", 30 } };
  return mymap;
}
map<string,int> m=   create_map();   
int main() 
{
    cout << "Hello, World!";
    for (map<string,int> x: m) 
       cout << x.first << ": " << x.second << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

the output of gcc  contain a lot of linkage error like

```
hello.cpp:(.text+0x135): undefined reference to `std::cout'                             
hello.cpp:(.text+0x13a): undefined reference to `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::operator<< <std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, char const*)
```

and g++ output was shorter

```
hello.cpp: In function 'int main()':
hello.cpp:19:29: error: conversion from 'std::pair<const std::basic_string<char>, int>' to non-scalar type 'std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>' requested
hello.cpp:20:18: error: 'class std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>' has no member named 'first'
hello.cpp:20:37: error: 'class std::map<std::basic_string<char>, int>' has no member named 'second'
```

the code is correct for 99.99%. i don't know really how to compile it properly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are some very different kind of errors you see.

> ```
> gcc hello.cpp -std=gnu++11
> ```

This tries to compile the code using the GNU c-compiler.
C++ source files are recognized and compiled regarding the c++ syntax, but the linker uses c standard libraries, and the c++ standard libraries aren't automatically linked.

There must be some difference with your source, since I can't reproduce the linker errors you're claiming with this [test](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b14cd5bc37ce01f6).

---

In the other case

> ```
>  g++ hello.cpp -std=gnu++11
> ```

your code is compiled using the c++ compiler, and

```
for (map<string,int> x: m)
```

is wrong regarding the type for `x` in the range based loop (which actually is `pair<const string,int>`).

You should simply change that to

```
for (const auto& x: m)
```

to get the code working.

`x` will be the type of the container *element* type, that is iterated over from `m`.

Here's a working [online demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d309033315080179).

Comment: do you know what flag should i add in order to use gcc?

Comment: @YonatanAmir Why would you want to do that? But you have to add an explicit flag to link with the `-lstdc++` library.

Answer (score 2):

Replace the loop with:

```
for (auto const& x: m) 
   cout << x.first << ": " << x.second << '\n';
```

Alternatively, you could use:

```
for (std::pair<string, int> x: m)
```

or

```
for (const std::pair<string, int>& x: m)
```

`const` because you do not want to change `x`. `&` to prevent a copy of the pair into `x`.

In the range based loop for an `std::map`, the variable that iterates over the container needs to be `std::pair<const Key, T>`. This is defined by the `value_type` for the container's [Member types](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map#Member_types).

Answer (score 1):

Since the type of x is `std::pair<const string,int>` you need to use instead (after comments):

```
for (const std::pair<const string,int>& x: m)
```

`const &` is added so that redundant *pair* copies are avoided (in the newest compilers they are probably avoided any way).

```
for (const auto& x: m)
```

may alternatively be used!

Comment: `auto` is way easier to memoize.

Comment: Leads to forgetting the respective underlying types, though.

Comment: But the correct type is `std::pair<const string,int>`